# Get JSON from Flask request only if it is valid

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask

I know that there are nice modules (like the [validator-collection](https://validator-collection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#)) that can check if a JSON is valid. But in my case, I want to achieve this with the built-in `Flask` capabilities: `is_json()` and `get_json()`.

This is what I have tried:

```py
import flask

def get_json_data():
    if flask.request.is_json():
        try:
           data = flask.request.get_json()
        except(ValueError):
            # get_json failed, return None
            # handle ValueError
    else:
        # is_json failed, return None
        # handle ValueError
```

After reading the docs, I could only find the `ValueError` exception being raised. If that is indeed the only exception, is my approach above correct in handling it and making sure that a `data` will hold JSON data only when a valid JSON request has been made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.is_json) states that `.is_json()` only checks if the request has a `Content-Type` that would indicate that the request contains JSON data.

> *property* `is_json`
>       Check if the mimetype indicates JSON data, either *application/json* or *application/*+json*.

It **does not** check whether the request data is actually JSON, so this check's usefulness is limited. When the client sends JSON but does not set an appropriate `Content-Type` header, or sets the header but sends invalid JSON, you learn nothing from `.is_json()`.

---

However, `.get_json()` *does* a "contains valid JSON" check: It tries to parse the request data as JSON, and either that works, in which case it returns the data, or it fails, in which case it throws an error. By default, `.get_json()` internally calls `.is_json()` anyway.

For what you want to do, I would say this is sufficient.

```
def get_json_data():
    data = flask.request.get_json()
```

If parsing is unsuccessful, there is no error thrown (compare [werkzeug docs](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.json.JSONMixin.get_json)). Instead "Bad Request" is returned to the client. If you want to change that behavior, override the `Request.on_json_loading_failed()` method with your own version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to educate my understanding: is `ValueError` the only possible exception that will be raised if the `get_json()` fails? Should I be cathing a more general exception in case `get_json` fails for other-than-value-error reasons?

Comment: Actually... I don't know for sure. Looking at the source code should clear things up.

Comment: Here's the link to the definition of `.get_json()` in the werkzeug GitHub repository (which flask is using) https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/d824659abe95ed31b1f9c355f88c4741da5a6e5f/src/werkzeug/wrappers/json.py#L94. The inline documentation is quite good.

Comment: Turns out there is no error thrown at all - how did it raise `ValueError` for you?